# How can I generate a plot with empty values?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, graphs

I want to add a plot that has some empty values to a tikz graph, but it does not compile: "Sorry, the requested column number 2 in table "dados2.txt" does not exist!?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[name=plot,
width=0.9\textwidth,
height=\axisdefaultheight,
xmin=0, xmax=300,
ymin=0, ymax=1.25,
minor tick num=4,
ytick distance=0.25,
xlabel={$V \, (\mathrm{mL})$},
ylabel={$\mathrm{Abs}$},
every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
legend pos={north east}]
\addplot[Dandelion, mark=none] table[x index=0,y index=2]{dados2.txt};
\addplot[JungleGreen, mark=none] table[x index=0,y index=8]{dados2.txt};
\addplot[SeaGreen, mark=none] table[x index=0,y index=9]{dados2.txt};
\addplot[Goldenrod, mark=none] table[x index=0,y index=10]{dados2.txt};
\addplot[RedOrange, mark=none] table[x index=0,y index=11]{dados2.txt};
\addlegendentry{SR2};
\addlegendentry{SR6};
\addlegendentry{SR7};
\addlegendentry{SR8};
\addlegendentry{SR9};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{MB+ - 1 mL}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

dados2.txt:

```
0                                           
1                                           
2                                           
3                                           
4                                           
5                                           
6                                           
7                                           
8                                           
9                                           
10                                          
11                                          
12                                          
13                                          
14                              1.0221          
15                              1.0208  0.9137      
16                              1.0185  0.9034  0.7171  0.7131
17                  1.6323  1.6355      1.0152  0.8979  0.6974  0.6956
18                  1.6163  1.6199  1.5885  1.0121  0.8904  0.6777  0.678
19                  1.5998  1.6042  1.5694  1.0098  0.8832  0.6588  0.6617
20                  1.5829  1.5881  1.5512  1.0071  0.8752  0.6402  0.6466
21          1.2006  1.5678  1.5663  1.5728  1.5327  1.0041  0.868   0.622   0.6314
22          1.1853  1.5491  1.5496  1.5572  1.5141  1.0014  0.8611  0.6041  0.6161
23      0.7071  1.1696  1.5306  1.5333  1.5413  1.496   0.9988  0.8544  0.5865  0.6012
24      0.6957  1.1539  1.5126  1.5168  1.5257  1.4783  0.9961  0.8474  0.5693  0.5872
25      0.6849  1.1386  1.4943  1.5001  1.5105  1.4611  0.9934  0.8404  0.5526  0.5738
26      0.6742  1.1231  1.4762  1.4832  1.4953  1.4443  0.9907  0.8336  0.5364  0.5606
27      0.6635  1.1078  1.4581  1.467   1.4803  1.4274  0.9881  0.8267  0.5205  0.5479
28      0.6528  1.0926  1.4401  1.4512  1.4653  1.4107  0.9854  0.8198  0.5049  0.5355
29      0.6422  1.0775  1.4222  1.4354  1.4504  1.3942  0.9827  0.8129  0.4898  0.5234
30      0.6317  1.0625  1.4044  1.4192  1.4352  1.378   0.9801  0.806   0.4747  0.5117
31      0.6213  1.0478  1.3868  1.4029  1.4192  1.3619  0.9776  0.7991  0.4598  0.5004
32      0.6111  1.0331  1.3691  1.3864  1.4038  1.3464  0.9751  0.7922  0.4454  0.4895
33      0.6011  1.0186  1.3517  1.3694  1.3892  1.3311  0.9725  0.7856  0.4311  0.4787
34      0.591   1.0042  1.3343  1.3532  1.3746  1.3161  0.9699  0.7789  0.4172  0.4683
35      0.5812  0.9898  1.3171  1.3372  1.3602  1.3013  0.9674  0.7723  0.4035  0.4582
36      0.5714  0.9756  1.3001  1.3217  1.3458  1.2867  0.9649  0.7659  0.3902  0.4484
37      0.5618  0.9615  1.2831  1.3065  1.3315  1.2724  0.9626  0.7596  0.3773  0.4388
38      0.5522  0.9476  1.2663  1.2916  1.3176  1.2584  0.9601  0.7533  0.3647  0.4296
39      0.5428  0.9338  1.2497  1.2764  1.3037  1.2445  0.9577  0.7471  0.3525  0.4207
40      0.5334  0.9202  1.2333  1.2603  1.2901  1.231   0.9554  0.7408  0.3406  0.4119
41      0.5242  0.9067  1.2168  1.244   1.2766  1.2176  0.953   0.7346  0.3291  0.4035
42      0.5151  0.8933  1.2006  1.2278  1.2631  1.2045  0.9508  0.7284  0.3178  0.3954
43      0.5062  0.88    1.1844  1.212   1.2496  1.1917  0.9483  0.7223  0.307   0.3875
44      0.4974  0.8669  1.1685  1.1962  1.2362  1.179   0.946   0.7162  0.2964  0.3798
45      0.4886  0.8539  1.1526  1.1805  1.2228  1.1666  0.9436  0.7102  0.2861  0.3723
46      0.4801  0.8409  1.1368  1.1649  1.2096  1.1542  0.9412  0.7043  0.2761  0.3651
47      0.4717  0.8282  1.1212  1.1496  1.1965  1.142   0.9388  0.6984  0.2665  0.3581
48      0.4634  0.8154  1.1057  1.1342  1.1834  1.1299  0.9364  0.6926  0.257   0.3514
49      0.4552  0.8029  1.0904  1.119   1.1705  1.118   0.9341  0.6866  0.2479  0.3447
50  0.2001  0.447   0.7903  1.0752  1.1038  1.1579  1.1065  0.9317  0.6808  0.2389  0.3384
51  0.1965  0.4391  0.778   1.06    1.0885  1.1452  1.0951  0.9292  0.6751  0.2304  0.3322
52  0.1937  0.4312  0.7658  1.0451  1.0732  1.1326  1.0839  0.9268  0.6694  0.2221  0.3263
53  0.1899  0.4235  0.7536  1.0302  1.0578  1.1202  1.0728  0.9244  0.6638  0.2141  0.3205
54  0.1856  0.4157  0.7417  1.0154  1.0426  1.1081  1.0619  0.922   0.6582  0.2063  0.3149
55  0.1816  0.4082  0.7298  1.0009  1.0276  1.096   1.0513  0.9197  0.6527  0.1989  0.3095
56  0.1781  0.4007  0.7179  0.9863  1.0126  1.0839  1.0408  0.9173  0.6472  0.1917  0.3042
57  0.1747  0.3933  0.7063  0.9719  0.9977  1.0719  1.0305  0.9149  0.6418  0.1847  0.2991
58  0.1713  0.386   0.6948  0.9576  0.9829  1.0599  1.0203  0.9127  0.6363  0.1781  0.2942
59  0.1678  0.3788  0.6833  0.9434  0.9683  1.0478  1.0103  0.9103  0.6308  0.1716  0.2895
60  0.1643  0.3717  0.672   0.9294  0.9536  1.0358  1.0005  0.908   0.6252  0.1654  0.285
61  0.1609  0.3647  0.6608  0.9154  0.9392  1.024   0.9907  0.9057  0.6197  0.1595  0.2805
62  0.1574  0.3578  0.6498  0.9017  0.9249  1.0123  0.9812  0.9034  0.6142  0.1537  0.2762
63  0.1541  0.351   0.6389  0.8881  0.9103  1.0007  0.9718  0.901   0.6087  0.1483  0.2719
64  0.1511  0.3443  0.6281  0.8746  0.8959  0.9892  0.9626  0.8987  0.6031  0.143   0.2677
65  0.148   0.3377  0.6174  0.8613  0.8815  0.9779  0.9534  0.8964  0.5975  0.1379  0.2636
66  0.1452  0.3311  0.6069  0.8481  0.8672  0.9665  0.9445  0.8941  0.5919  0.133   0.2596
67  0.1423  0.3247  0.5964  0.835   0.8531  0.9554  0.9357  0.8918  0.5862  0.1281  0.2556
68  0.1396  0.3183  0.5861  0.822   0.8393  0.9444  0.927   0.8895  0.5804  0.1235  0.2518
69  0.137   0.3121  0.5759  0.8093  0.8256  0.9334  0.9184  0.8872  0.5748  0.1189  0.2482
70  0.1343  0.306   0.566   0.7966  0.812   0.9225  0.91    0.8849  0.5693  0.1146  0.2448
71  0.1317  0.2999  0.5561  0.7842  0.7984  0.9117  0.9017  0.8826  0.5639  0.1103  0.2414
72  0.1291  0.2939  0.5463  0.7717  0.7851  0.9009  0.8934  0.8803  0.5585  0.1063  0.2381
73  0.1265  0.2881  0.5366  0.7596  0.7718  0.8904  0.8854  0.8779  0.5533  0.1023  0.235
74  0.1241  0.2823  0.5271  0.7474  0.7586  0.8798  0.8774  0.8756  0.5481  0.0986  0.2319
75  0.1215  0.2767  0.5176  0.7355  0.7457  0.8692  0.8696  0.8734  0.5429  0.0949  0.2291
76  0.1192  0.2711  0.5083  0.7237  0.7328  0.8589  0.8619  0.8711  0.5378  0.0914  0.2262
77  0.1167  0.2656  0.4992  0.712   0.7201  0.8485  0.8543  0.8688  0.5326  0.088   0.2235
78  0.1144  0.2602  0.4901  0.7005  0.7076  0.8384  0.8469  0.8665  0.5274  0.0846  0.2209
79  0.1121  0.2549  0.4812  0.689   0.6952  0.8282  0.8396  0.8642  0.5224  0.0815  0.2183
80  0.1099  0.2496  0.4724  0.6777  0.6828  0.8183  0.8323  0.8619  0.5173  0.0785  0.2157
81  0.1078  0.2446  0.4636  0.6665  0.6707  0.8084  0.8252  0.8597  0.5124  0.0755  0.2133
82  0.1058  0.2394  0.455   0.6555  0.6586  0.7986  0.8182  0.8574  0.5074  0.0727  0.211
83  0.1038  0.2345  0.4465  0.6447  0.6467  0.789   0.8113  0.8551  0.5025  0.0699  0.2086
84  0.1019  0.2296  0.4382  0.6339  0.6348  0.7794  0.8045  0.8529  0.4977  0.0673  0.2064
85  0.0998  0.2249  0.43    0.6233  0.6231  0.7701  0.7978  0.8506  0.493   0.0647  0.2043
86  0.0979  0.2203  0.4219  0.6127  0.6116  0.7607  0.7912  0.8483  0.4882  0.0622  0.2023
87  0.096   0.2157  0.4139  0.6024  0.6003  0.7514  0.7847  0.8461  0.4834  0.06    0.2002
88  0.0941  0.2111  0.406   0.5921  0.5891  0.7422  0.7783  0.8438  0.4786  0.0579  0.1983
89  0.0921  0.2067  0.3983  0.582   0.578   0.7331  0.772   0.8416  0.4738  0.056   0.1964
90  0.0904  0.2024  0.3907  0.572   0.5668  0.7241  0.7658  0.8394  0.469   0.0541  0.1944
91  0.0885  0.1981  0.3831  0.5621  0.5558  0.7151  0.7597  0.8372  0.4643  0.0524  0.1927
92  0.0866  0.194   0.3758  0.5523  0.5447  0.7062  0.7537  0.8349  0.4595  0.0507  0.191
93  0.0849  0.1898  0.3685  0.5427  0.5336  0.6974  0.7477  0.8327  0.4548  0.0491  0.1892
94  0.0832  0.1858  0.3614  0.5332  0.5228  0.6885  0.7419  0.8305  0.4502  0.0475  0.1876
95  0.0815  0.1819  0.3544  0.5237  0.5123  0.6798  0.7362  0.8282  0.4456  0.046   0.1861
96  0.0798  0.178   0.3474  0.5145  0.5018  0.6713  0.7304  0.826   0.4411  0.0446  0.1845
97  0.0782  0.1743  0.3406  0.5054  0.4915  0.6628  0.7249  0.8238  0.4367  0.0431  0.183
98  0.0767  0.1706  0.334   0.4963  0.4812  0.6543  0.7195  0.8216  0.4324  0.0418  0.1815
99  0.0752  0.1669  0.3274  0.4876  0.4713  0.646   0.7141  0.8194  0.4282  0.0404  0.1801
100 0.0737  0.1633  0.3209  0.4789  0.4614  0.6378  0.7088  0.8172  0.424   0.0392  0.1787
101 0.0722  0.1599  0.3145  0.4705  0.4519  0.6297  0.7035  0.8151  0.4198  0.0379  0.1774
102 0.0707  0.1564  0.3083  0.4621  0.4426  0.6217  0.6983  0.8128  0.4158  0.0368  0.1759
103 0.0692  0.1531  0.3021  0.4537  0.4333  0.6138  0.6934  0.8107  0.4117  0.0357  0.1747
104 0.0678  0.1499  0.2961  0.4454  0.4241  0.606   0.6882  0.8085  0.4076  0.0347  0.1735
105 0.0664  0.1466  0.2901  0.4373  0.415   0.5983  0.6834  0.8064  0.4036  0.0337  0.1723
106 0.065   0.1435  0.2843  0.4292  0.406   0.5905  0.6786  0.8042  0.3997  0.0328  0.1712
107 0.0638  0.1404  0.2785  0.4212  0.3972  0.583   0.6738  0.8021  0.3959  0.0319  0.1701
108 0.0624  0.1374  0.2729  0.4133  0.3886  0.5755  0.6691  0.8001  0.392   0.031   0.1691
109 0.0611  0.1345  0.2675  0.4056  0.3801  0.5681  0.6645  0.798   0.3881  0.0303  0.1682
110 0.0598  0.1315  0.262   0.398   0.3717  0.5607  0.66    0.7959  0.3843  0.0295  0.1672
111 0.0587  0.1287  0.2566  0.3905  0.3633  0.5534  0.6555  0.7939  0.3804  0.0287  0.1663
112 0.0575  0.126   0.2514  0.3832  0.3551  0.5462  0.651   0.7918  0.3764  0.0282  0.1654
113 0.0563  0.1233  0.2463  0.3761  0.3472  0.539   0.6467  0.7897  0.3724  0.0275  0.1645
114 0.0551  0.1206  0.2412  0.369   0.3393  0.5321  0.6424  0.7876  0.3685  0.0271  0.1636
115 0.0539  0.1181  0.2363  0.362   0.3316  0.5251  0.6382  0.7855  0.3645  0.0266  0.1628
116 0.0529  0.1155  0.2314  0.3551  0.3239  0.5182  0.634   0.7835  0.3606  0.0261  0.162
117 0.0518  0.1132  0.2266  0.3485  0.3165  0.5114  0.63    0.7813  0.3566  0.0256  0.1613
118 0.0509  0.1108  0.2219  0.3418  0.3091  0.5045  0.626   0.7792  0.3527  0.0251  0.1606
119 0.0499  0.1085  0.2173  0.3354  0.3019  0.4978  0.622   0.7771  0.3487  0.0246  0.1599
120 0.0489  0.1062  0.2128  0.329   0.2949  0.4913  0.6181  0.775   0.3449  0.0242  0.1592
121 0.0479  0.1039  0.2084  0.3228  0.288   0.4847  0.6142  0.7729  0.341   0.0237  0.1587
122 0.047   0.1017  0.204   0.3166  0.2813  0.4783  0.6106  0.7708  0.3371  0.0232  0.158
123 0.0461  0.0997  0.1998  0.3105  0.2746  0.4719  0.6069  0.7687  0.3332  0.0227  0.1573
124 0.0452  0.0975  0.1957  0.3046  0.2682  0.4656  0.6032  0.7665  0.3295  0.0222  0.1567
125 0.0443  0.0955  0.1915  0.2988  0.2619  0.4594  0.5996  0.7644  0.3258  0.0218  0.1561
126 0.0434  0.0936  0.1875  0.2931  0.2556  0.4534  0.5961  0.7623  0.3221  0.0214  0.1556
127 0.0427  0.0917  0.1836  0.2874  0.2494  0.4473  0.5926  0.7602  0.3185  0.021   0.155
128 0.0419  0.0898  0.1798  0.2818  0.2435  0.4414  0.5892  0.758   0.3148  0.0207  0.1544
129 0.0411  0.088   0.176   0.2764  0.2375  0.4355  0.5857  0.7559  0.3113  0.0203  0.154
130 0.0403  0.0862  0.1723  0.271   0.2318  0.4297  0.5824  0.7538  0.3078  0.02    0.1534
131 0.0396  0.0844  0.1687  0.2659  0.2263  0.424   0.5791  0.7516  0.3043  0.0198  0.1529
132 0.0389  0.0826  0.1651  0.2607  0.2209  0.4182  0.5759  0.7495  0.3009  0.0194  0.1525
133 0.0381  0.081   0.1616  0.2557  0.2154  0.4127  0.5728  0.7473  0.2975  0.0192  0.152
134 0.0374  0.0794  0.1582  0.2508  0.2101  0.4073  0.5696  0.7453  0.2942  0.0189  0.1515
135 0.0368  0.0778  0.1548  0.246   0.2049  0.4019  0.5665  0.7431  0.2909  0.0187  0.151
136 0.0361  0.0762  0.1516  0.2412  0.1999  0.3967  0.5635  0.741   0.2876  0.0185  0.1505
137 0.0354  0.0747  0.1484  0.2365  0.195   0.3914  0.5606  0.739   0.2844  0.0183  0.1501
138 0.0348  0.0732  0.1452  0.2319  0.1902  0.3861  0.5576  0.7369  0.2812  0.0181  0.1497
139 0.0342  0.0718  0.1422  0.2274  0.1857  0.3811  0.5547  0.7348  0.2781  0.0179  0.1492
140 0.0336  0.0704  0.1392  0.2231  0.1813  0.376   0.5519  0.7328  0.2749  0.0177  0.1489
141 0.0331  0.0691  0.1363  0.2188  0.177   0.371   0.5492  0.7307  0.2718  0.0176  0.1485
142 0.0325  0.0677  0.1334  0.2145  0.1727  0.3661  0.5464  0.7286  0.2688  0.0175  0.1482
143 0.0319  0.0665  0.1306  0.2104  0.1684  0.3612  0.5437  0.7266  0.2657  0.0174  0.148
144 0.0314  0.0652  0.1279  0.2063  0.1641  0.3564  0.541   0.7245  0.2627  0.0175  0.1477
145 0.0309  0.064   0.1252  0.2024  0.1599  0.3515  0.5384  0.7225  0.2597  0.0174  0.1474
146 0.0304  0.0629  0.1225  0.1985  0.1558  0.3468  0.5357  0.7204  0.2568  0.0174  0.1472
147 0.0299  0.0617  0.1201  0.1947  0.1519  0.3421  0.5333  0.7183  0.2539  0.0174  0.1469
148 0.0294  0.0607  0.1175  0.1909  0.1481  0.3374  0.5307  0.7163  0.251   0.0174  0.1466
149 0.029   0.0596  0.1152  0.1873  0.1444  0.3327  0.5283  0.7143  0.2481  0.0173  0.1464
150 0.0285  0.0586  0.1128  0.1837  0.1407  0.3281  0.5258  0.7122  0.2453  0.0172  0.1462
151 0.0281  0.0575  0.1105  0.1802  0.137   0.3236  0.5234  0.7102  0.2425  0.0171  0.146
152 0.0277  0.0566  0.1082  0.1768  0.1335  0.319   0.5211  0.7081  0.2397  0.017   0.1459
153 0.0272  0.0557  0.1061  0.1734  0.1302  0.3144  0.5187  0.7061  0.237   0.017   0.1456
154 0.0269  0.0548  0.1039  0.1701  0.1271  0.31    0.5164  0.7041  0.2344  0.0169  0.1454
155 0.0265  0.0539  0.1017  0.1669  0.124   0.3056  0.5142  0.702   0.2319  0.0168  0.1452
156 0.0262  0.0531  0.0997  0.1637  0.121   0.3013  0.512   0.7 0.2295  0.0168  0.1449
157 0.0258  0.0522  0.0976  0.1607  0.1182  0.297   0.5098  0.698   0.2271  0.0167  0.1445
158 0.0255  0.0513  0.0957  0.1577  0.1152  0.2929  0.5077  0.6961  0.2247  0.0166  0.1443
159 0.0252  0.0504  0.0938  0.1547  0.1123  0.2887  0.5057  0.6941  0.2223  0.0165  0.144
160 0.0249  0.0496  0.092   0.1518  0.1094  0.2846  0.5035  0.6922  0.22    0.0165  0.1437
161 0.0246  0.0488  0.0901  0.149   0.1066  0.2806  0.5015  0.6902  0.2177  0.0164  0.1434
162 0.0243  0.048   0.0884  0.1463  0.1038  0.2766  0.4995  0.6882  0.2152  0.0163  0.1431
163 0.024   0.0472  0.0866  0.1436  0.1012  0.2727  0.4975  0.6863  0.2129  0.0163  0.1429
164 0.0237  0.0464  0.0849  0.141   0.0986  0.2689  0.4956  0.6843  0.2104  0.0162  0.1427
165 0.0233  0.0457  0.0833  0.1384  0.0962  0.2651  0.4937  0.6823  0.2079  0.0161  0.1425
166 0.023   0.0449  0.0816  0.1358  0.0937  0.2614  0.4918  0.6804  0.2053  0.016   0.1424
167 0.0228  0.0442  0.0802  0.1334  0.0912  0.2578  0.49    0.6784  0.2028  0.016   0.1423
168 0.0225  0.0436  0.0786  0.131   0.089   0.2542  0.4882  0.6765  0.2003  0.0159  0.1424
169 0.0221  0.0429  0.0771  0.1286  0.0868  0.2506  0.4865  0.6746  0.1978  0.0159  0.1423
170 0.0218  0.0423  0.0757  0.1264  0.0846  0.2471  0.4844  0.6726  0.1952  0.0158  0.1423
171 0.0214  0.0416  0.0743  0.1241  0.0825  0.2436  0.4828  0.6706  0.1927  0.0157  0.1422
172 0.0211  0.041   0.0728  0.1219  0.0805  0.2402  0.4811  0.6687  0.1904  0.0157  0.1422
173 0.0208  0.0404  0.0716  0.1198  0.0784  0.2368  0.4795  0.6667  0.188   0.0156  0.142
174 0.0204  0.0398  0.0703  0.1177  0.0766  0.2335  0.4776  0.6647  0.1856  0.0155  0.1419
175 0.0201  0.0392  0.0689  0.1156  0.0747  0.2302  0.476   0.6628  0.1832  0.0155  0.1418
176 0.0197  0.0387  0.0678  0.1136  0.073   0.227   0.4745  0.6608  0.181   0.0154  0.1418
177 0.0194  0.0382  0.0666  0.1115  0.0714  0.2238  0.4728  0.6588  0.1788  0.0154  0.1417
178 0.019   0.0376  0.0654  0.1096  0.0701  0.2207  0.4713  0.6569  0.1766  0.0153  0.1417
179 0.0186  0.0372  0.0643  0.1078  0.0689  0.2176  0.4697  0.655   0.1745  0.0153  0.1417
180 0.0184  0.0367  0.0632  0.106   0.0677  0.2146  0.4682  0.653   0.1724  0.0153  0.1417
181 0.018   0.0363  0.0621  0.1041  0.0666  0.2117  0.4668  0.651   0.1703  0.0152  0.1419
182 0.0177  0.0359  0.0611  0.1024  0.0652  0.2087  0.4653  0.6491  0.1683  0.0152  0.142
183 0.0174  0.0354  0.06    0.1007  0.0636  0.2058  0.4639  0.6472  0.1662  0.0152  0.1423
184 0.0172  0.0351  0.059   0.099   0.0618  0.203   0.4625  0.6453  0.1643  0.0152  0.1428
185 0.0169  0.0347  0.0581  0.0974  0.06    0.2001  0.4612  0.6433  0.1623  0.0152  0.1432
186 0.0167  0.0343  0.0571  0.0958  0.0577  0.1974  0.4598  0.6414  0.1604  0.0151  0.1434
187 0.0165  0.0339  0.0561  0.0942  0.0562  0.1946  0.4584  0.6396  0.1584  0.0151  0.1437
188 0.0163  0.0335  0.0553  0.0928  0.0548  0.1918  0.4571  0.6376  0.1565  0.015   0.1437
189 0.0161  0.0332  0.0544  0.0912  0.0536  0.1889  0.4558  0.6358  0.1547  0.0149  0.1432
190 0.0159  0.0329  0.0535  0.0898  0.0524  0.1862  0.4544  0.6339  0.1528  0.0149  0.1425
191 0.0157  0.0325  0.0526  0.0885  0.0512  0.1835  0.4531  0.632   0.151   0.0148  0.1418
192 0.0156  0.0322  0.0519  0.0871  0.05    0.1808  0.4522  0.6302  0.1492  0.0148  0.1411
193 0.0153  0.0319  0.0511  0.0857  0.0489  0.1783  0.4509  0.6283  0.1474  0.0148  0.1405
194 0.0152  0.0317  0.0504  0.0844  0.0479  0.1757  0.4497  0.6264  0.1456  0.0147  0.14
195 0.015   0.0313  0.0495  0.0832  0.0469  0.1733  0.4485  0.6246  0.1439  0.0147  0.1396
196 0.0149  0.031   0.0488  0.082   0.046   0.1708  0.4474  0.6227  0.1422  0.0147  0.1393
197 0.0147  0.0308  0.0481  0.0808  0.045   0.1684  0.4462  0.6208  0.1404  0.0146  0.139
198 0.0146  0.0305  0.0474  0.0796  0.0441  0.1661  0.4451  0.6189  0.1387  0.0146  0.1387
199 0.0145  0.0302  0.0467  0.0785  0.0431  0.1638  0.444   0.6171  0.1369  0.0146  0.1384
200 0.0143  0.0299  0.0461  0.0773  0.0423  0.1615  0.4428  0.6153  0.1354  0.0146  0.1381
201 0.0141  0.0297  0.0454  0.0762  0.0414  0.1592  0.4418  0.6134  0.1337  0.0146  0.1379
202 0.014   0.0294  0.0449  0.0751  0.0405  0.157   0.4407  0.6116  0.1321  0.0145  0.1377
203 0.0138  0.0292  0.0442  0.0741  0.0396  0.1548  0.4397  0.6098  0.1305  0.0145  0.1375
204 0.0137  0.029   0.0437  0.0731  0.0388  0.1527  0.4387  0.6079  0.129   0.0146  0.1373
205 0.0136  0.0287  0.043   0.0721  0.0381  0.1505  0.4376  0.606   0.1274  0.0145  0.1373
206 0.0135  0.0285  0.0426  0.0712  0.0373  0.1485  0.4366  0.6042  0.1258  0.0145  0.1371
207 0.0133  0.0282  0.0419  0.0702  0.0366  0.1465  0.4357  0.6024  0.1243  0.0145  0.137
208 0.0132  0.028   0.0414  0.0693  0.0359  0.1445  0.4346  0.6006  0.1228  0.0145  0.1369
209 0.0131  0.0278  0.041   0.0685  0.0352  0.1426  0.4336  0.5988  0.1213  0.0145  0.1368
210 0.0131  0.0276  0.0405  0.0676  0.0345  0.1407  0.4327  0.5969  0.1198  0.0145  0.1367
211 0.013   0.0274  0.0399  0.0667  0.0339  0.1387  0.4318  0.5951  0.1184  0.0144  0.1366
212 0.0127  0.0272  0.0395  0.0659  0.0332  0.1369  0.4308  0.5933  0.1169  0.0145  0.1366
213 0.0127  0.0271  0.039   0.065   0.0327  0.1351  0.43    0.5915  0.1155  0.0144  0.1366
214 0.0126  0.0269  0.0386  0.0643  0.0321  0.1333  0.429   0.5897  0.1141  0.0144  0.1365
215 0.0125  0.0267  0.0381  0.0636  0.0315  0.1315  0.4282  0.5879  0.1127  0.0144  0.1364
216 0.0125  0.0265  0.0378  0.0628  0.031   0.1297  0.4273  0.5862  0.1114  0.0143  0.1364
217 0.0123  0.0264  0.0374  0.0621  0.0305  0.1279  0.4265  0.5844  0.11    0.0143  0.1363
218 0.0122  0.0262  0.037   0.0613  0.0299  0.1261  0.4256  0.5826  0.1086  0.0142  0.1362
219 0.0122  0.0261  0.0365  0.0607  0.0295  0.1244  0.4248  0.5808  0.1073  0.0142  0.1362
220 0.0122  0.026   0.0362  0.06    0.029   0.1228  0.424   0.579   0.106   0.0141  0.1361
221 0.0121  0.0258  0.0358  0.0594  0.0285  0.121   0.4231  0.5773  0.1048  0.0141  0.136
222 0.012   0.0257  0.0354  0.0587  0.0281  0.1194  0.4223  0.5755  0.1035  0.0141  0.1361
223 0.012   0.0255  0.0351  0.0581  0.0277  0.1177  0.4215  0.5738  0.1023  0.0141  0.136
224 0.0119  0.0255  0.0348  0.0575  0.0273  0.1161  0.4208  0.572   0.1011  0.014   0.1359
225 0.0118  0.0253  0.0345  0.0569  0.0268  0.1145  0.42    0.5702  0.0999  0.014   0.1359
226 0.0118  0.0252  0.0341  0.0564  0.0265  0.1129  0.4193  0.5685  0.0987  0.014   0.1359
227 0.0117  0.0251  0.0338  0.0558  0.0261  0.1114  0.4186  0.5667  0.0975  0.0139  0.1359
228 0.0117  0.025   0.0335  0.0552  0.0257  0.1098  0.4179  0.5649  0.0963  0.014   0.1358
229 0.0117  0.0249  0.0332  0.0547  0.0254  0.1083  0.4171  0.5632  0.0952  0.0139  0.1358
230 0.0117  0.0248  0.0329  0.0543  0.025   0.1069  0.4165  0.5614  0.094   0.0139  0.1358
231 0.0116  0.0247  0.0327  0.0537  0.0247  0.1054  0.4157  0.5596  0.0929  0.014   0.1357
232 0.0116  0.0246  0.0323  0.0533  0.0243  0.104   0.4151  0.558   0.0918  0.014   0.1357
233 0.0116  0.0245  0.0321  0.0527  0.0241  0.1026  0.4144  0.5562  0.0907  0.014   0.1357
234 0.0115  0.0244  0.0318  0.0523  0.0238  0.1011  0.4138  0.5545  0.0896  0.014   0.1357
235 0.0114  0.0244  0.0316  0.0518  0.0235  0.0998  0.4131  0.5528  0.0886  0.014   0.1358
236 0.0115  0.0243  0.0313  0.0513  0.0233  0.0985  0.4125  0.551   0.0875  0.0139  0.1357
237 0.0115  0.0242  0.0311  0.0509  0.0231  0.0972  0.4119  0.5493  0.0864  0.0139  0.1357
238 0.0115  0.0242  0.0309  0.0505  0.0228  0.0959  0.4113  0.5476  0.0854  0.014   0.1357
239 0.0114  0.024   0.0306  0.0501  0.0226  0.0946  0.4107  0.5458  0.0844  0.014   0.1356
240 0.0114  0.024   0.0305  0.0497  0.0225  0.0933  0.41    0.5441  0.0834  0.0139  0.1356
241 0.0114  0.0239  0.0302  0.0493  0.0223  0.0921  0.4095  0.5424  0.0824  0.0139  0.1355
242 0.0114  0.0238  0.03    0.0489  0.0222  0.0909  0.4089  0.5408  0.0814  0.014   0.1354
243 0.0114  0.0238  0.0299  0.0485  0.0221  0.0897  0.4083  0.539   0.0804  0.014   0.1353
244 0.0114  0.0237  0.0297  0.0481  0.0219  0.0886  0.4077  0.5374  0.0794  0.014   0.1353
245 0.0113  0.0236  0.0295  0.0478  0.0217  0.0874  0.4072  0.5357  0.0785  0.0141  0.1352
246 0.0113  0.0236  0.0293  0.0475  0.0215  0.0863  0.4067  0.534   0.0776  0.0141  0.1352
247 0.0113  0.0235  0.0291  0.0471  0.0213  0.0852  0.4062  0.5323  0.0766  0.014   0.1352
248 0.0112  0.0235  0.0289  0.0468  0.021   0.0841  0.4056  0.5306  0.0757  0.0141  0.1351
249 0.0111  0.0234  0.0288  0.0464  0.0208  0.083   0.4051  0.529   0.0748  0.0141  0.1351
250 0.0111  0.0233  0.0286  0.0462  0.0204  0.0819  0.4046  0.5273  0.0739  0.0141  0.1351
251 0.0111  0.0233  0.0284  0.0459  0.0201  0.0809  0.4041  0.5256  0.073   0.0142  0.135
252 0.0111  0.0232  0.0283  0.0456  0.02    0.0798  0.4036  0.524   0.0721  0.0141  0.135
253 0.011   0.0233  0.0282  0.0452  0.0198  0.0788  0.4032  0.5223  0.0713  0.0141  0.135
254 0.0109  0.0233  0.028   0.045   0.0196  0.0778  0.4026  0.5206  0.0705  0.0142  0.1349
255 0.0109  0.0232  0.0278  0.0446  0.0195  0.0768  0.4021  0.519   0.0696  0.0141  0.1349
256 0.0108  0.0232  0.0277  0.0444  0.0194  0.0759  0.4016  0.5173  0.0687  0.0141  0.1349
257 0.0108  0.0232  0.0276  0.0442  0.0192  0.0749  0.4012  0.5157  0.068   0.0141  0.1348
258 0.0108  0.0232  0.0275  0.0439  0.0191  0.0739  0.4007  0.5141  0.0672  0.014   0.1348
259 0.0107  0.0231  0.0274  0.0437  0.019   0.0728  0.4003  0.5124  0.0664  0.0141  0.1348
260 0.0107  0.0232  0.0273  0.0434  0.0188  0.072   0.3999  0.5108  0.0656  0.014   0.1348
261 0.0106  0.0231  0.0271  0.0431  0.0188  0.071   0.3993  0.5091  0.0649  0.014   0.1348
262 0.0106  0.0231  0.0271  0.043   0.0187  0.0701  0.3989  0.5075  0.0642  0.014   0.1347
263 0.0105  0.0231  0.027   0.0427  0.0186  0.0692  0.3985  0.5059  0.0634  0.0139  0.1346
264 0.0104  0.0231  0.0268  0.0425  0.0186  0.0683  0.3981  0.5043  0.0627  0.0139  0.1346
265 0.0104  0.0231  0.0267  0.0423  0.0186  0.0674  0.3977  0.5026  0.062   0.0139  0.1345
266 0.0103  0.0231  0.0267  0.0421  0.0186  0.0666  0.3972  0.501   0.0612  0.0139  0.1345
267 0.0103  0.0231  0.0266  0.0419  0.0185  0.0657  0.3969  0.4994  0.0605  0.0139  0.1345
268 0.0102  0.023   0.0265  0.0417  0.0185  0.0649  0.3965  0.4978  0.0599  0.0139  0.1345
269 0.0102  0.023   0.0265  0.0415  0.0183  0.0641  0.3961  0.4962  0.0592  0.0139  0.1344
270 0.0101  0.0229  0.0264  0.0414  0.0182  0.0634  0.3957  0.4946  0.0586  0.0139  0.1344
271 0.01    0.0229  0.0263  0.0412  0.018   0.0626  0.3954  0.493   0.0579  0.0139  0.1343
272 0.0099  0.0229  0.0262  0.0409  0.0174  0.0619  0.3949  0.4914  0.0573  0.0139  0.1343
273 0.0099  0.0228  0.0262  0.0408  0.0171  0.0611  0.3946  0.4898  0.0566  0.0138  0.1342
274 0.0099  0.0228  0.0262  0.0406  0.0171  0.0604  0.3943  0.4882  0.056   0.0139  0.1343
275 0.0099  0.0226  0.0261  0.0405  0.017   0.0597  0.3939  0.4867  0.0554  0.0138  0.1342
276 0.0098  0.0226  0.0261  0.0403  0.0169  0.059   0.3935  0.4851  0.0547  0.0138  0.1342
277 0.0097  0.0226  0.026   0.0402  0.0167  0.0583  0.3932  0.4835  0.0542  0.0138  0.1342
278 0.0097  0.0225  0.026   0.0401  0.0166  0.0576  0.3929  0.482   0.0535  0.0138  0.1342
279 0.0097  0.0225  0.0259  0.0399  0.0166  0.0569  0.3925  0.4804  0.053   0.0139  0.1341
280 0.0096  0.0225  0.0258  0.0398  0.0165  0.0562  0.3922  0.4789  0.0524  0.0138  0.1342
281 0.0096  0.0225  0.0258  0.0396  0.0164  0.0555  0.3919  0.4772  0.0518  0.0138  0.1341
282 0.0096  0.0224  0.0258  0.0395  0.0164  0.0549  0.3915  0.4757  0.0513  0.0138  0.1341
283 0.0095  0.0223  0.0257  0.0394  0.0163  0.0542  0.3912  0.4742  0.0507  0.0137  0.1342
284 0.0095  0.0223  0.0256  0.0392  0.0163  0.0536  0.3909  0.4726  0.0502  0.0138  0.1341
285 0.0094  0.0222  0.0255  0.0391  0.0162  0.053   0.3906  0.4711  0.0497  0.0138  0.1341
286 0.0095  0.0222  0.0254  0.039   0.0162  0.0523  0.3902  0.4696  0.0491  0.0138  0.1342
287 0.0095  0.0222  0.0253  0.0389  0.0162  0.0517  0.39    0.468   0.0485  0.0138  0.1342
288 0.0095  0.0222  0.0252  0.0389  0.0162  0.0511  0.3897  0.4665  0.048   0.0138  0.1341
289 0.0095  0.0222  0.0251  0.0387  0.0162  0.0505  0.3894  0.4649  0.0475  0.0138  0.1342
290 0.0094  0.0221  0.025   0.0386  0.0161  0.0499  0.3891  0.4634  0.0471  0.0138  0.1341
291 0.0095  0.0221  0.025   0.0385  0.0162  0.0494  0.3888  0.4618  0.0466  0.0138  0.1341
292 0.0095  0.0222  0.0249  0.0384  0.0161  0.0488  0.3885  0.4603  0.0461  0.0138  0.1341
293 0.0094  0.0221  0.0249  0.0383  0.0161  0.0483  0.3882  0.4588  0.0456  0.0138  0.1341
294 0.0094  0.0221  0.0247  0.0382  0.0161  0.0477  0.3879  0.4572  0.0451  0.0139  0.1341
295 0.0094  0.0221  0.0247  0.0381  0.0161  0.0473  0.3877  0.4557  0.0446  0.0139  0.134
296 0.0094  0.0221  0.0246  0.038   0.016   0.0468  0.3874  0.4542  0.0442  0.0138  0.134
297 0.0093  0.0222  0.0246  0.0379  0.016   0.0463  0.3871  0.4527  0.0438  0.0138  0.134
298 0.0094  0.0222  0.0245  0.0379  0.016   0.0458  0.3869  0.4512  0.0433  0.0138  0.1339
299 0.0094  0.0222  0.0244  0.0378  0.0159  0.0453  0.3866  0.4497  0.0428  0.0138  0.1339
300 0.0094  0.0222  0.0244  0.0377  0.0158  0.0449  0.3863  0.4482  0.0424  0.0138  0.1338
301 0.0094  0.0224  0.0243  0.0376  0.0158  0.0445  0.3861  0.4466  0.042   0.0138  0.1338
302 0.0094  0.0224  0.0243  0.0376  0.0157  0.0441  0.3859  0.4452  0.0415  0.0138  0.1338
303 0.0094  0.0225  0.0243  0.0374  0.0156  0.0437  0.3856  0.4437  0.0412  0.0138  0.1337
304 0.0094  0.0225  0.0242  0.0374  0.0156  0.0434  0.3854  0.4422  0.0407  0.0137  0.1338
305 0.0094  0.0226  0.0242  0.0373  0.0155  0.043   0.3851  0.4408  0.0403  0.0137  0.1337
306 0.0094  0.0226  0.0242  0.0373  0.0155  0.0426  0.3849  0.4393  0.04    0.0138  0.1337
307 0.0093  0.0227  0.0241  0.0372  0.0155  0.0423  0.3847  0.4378  0.0396  0.0138  0.1337
308 0.0093  0.0227  0.0241  0.0371  0.0154  0.0419  0.3844  0.4363  0.0392  0.0138  0.1337
309 0.0093  0.0228  0.0241  0.037   0.0154  0.0416  0.3841  0.4349  0.0388  0.0138  0.1336
310 0.0093  0.0228  0.0241  0.037   0.0155  0.0413  0.384   0.4334  0.0385  0.0138  0.1335
311 0.0093  0.0228  0.024   0.037   0.0155  0.0409  0.3838  0.4319  0.0381  0.0139  0.1335
312 0.0093  0.0227  0.024   0.0369  0.0154  0.0405  0.3836  0.4305  0.0377  0.0139  0.1336
313 0.0093  0.0227  0.024   0.0368  0.0154  0.0402  0.3833  0.4291  0.0374  0.0139  0.1336
314 0.0093  0.0227  0.0239  0.0368  0.0153  0.0397  0.3832      0.0371  0.014   0.1336
315 0.0093  0.0226  0.0239  0.0367  0.0152  0.0393  0.3829          0.0139  0.1336
316 0.0093  0.0225  0.0238  0.0367  0.0152  0.0388  0.3827              
317 0.0093  0.0225  0.0238  0.0367          0.3826              
318 0.0093  0.0223  0.0238  0.0366                          
319 0.0093  0.0224  0.0238  0.0365                          
320 0.0093  0.0223  0.0238  0.0365                          
321 0.0093  0.0222                                  
322 0.0092  0.0222                                  
323 0.0092                                      
324 0.0092                                      
325 0.0092                                      
326 0.0092                                      
327 0.0092                                      
328 0.0092                                      
329 0.0092                                      
330 0.0092                                      
331 0.0092                                      
332 0.0092                                      
333 0.0092                                      
334 0.0092                                      
335 0.0092                                      
336 0.0092                                      
337 0.0092                                      
338 0.0092                                      
339 0.0092                                      
340 0.0092                                      
341 0.0092                                      
342 0.0091                                      
343 0.0092                                      
344 0.0091                                      
345 0.0091                                      
346 0.0091                                      
347 0.0092                                      
348 0.0092                                      
349 0.0091                                      
350
```

I want it to appear like this:
[image]

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that . If your question is not about Dandelion's , do not use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have data in the first line (can be circumvented with `gnuplot [raw gnuplot]`) - so just place `nan` (not a number - “empty cell” placeholder) in the first line. You can also not use whitespace as a column separator as PGFPlots has no way of knowing when the next column starts unless you replace *all* empty cells with `nan`.

```
\begin{filecontents}{dados2.txt}
nan nan nan nan nan nan nan naa nan nan nan nan
14                              1.0221          
15                              1.0208  0.9137      
16                              1.0185  0.9034  0.7171  0.7131
17                  1.6323  1.6355      1.0152  0.8979  0.6974  0.6956
18                  1.6163  1.6199  1.5885  1.0121  0.8904  0.6777  0.678
19                  1.5998  1.6042  1.5694  1.0098  0.8832  0.6588  0.6617
20                  1.5829  1.5881  1.5512  1.0071  0.8752  0.6402  0.6466
21          1.2006  1.5678  1.5663  1.5728  1.5327  1.0041  0.868   0.622   0.6314
22          1.1853  1.5491  1.5496  1.5572  1.5141  1.0014  0.8611  0.6041  0.6161                      
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table[header=false, x index=0,y index=2]{dados2.txt};
\addplot table[header=false, x index=0,y index=8]{dados2.txt};
\addplot table[header=false, x index=0,y index=9]{dados2.txt};
\addplot table[header=false, x index=0,y index=10]{dados2.txt};
\addplot table[header=false, x index=0,y index=11]{dados2.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with some lineplots]

**Edit:** I am now thinking that `nan` in the first line does not really solve the underlying problem that PGFPlots does not know when the next cell starts. It would be much better to store/convert your data to `cvs`(comma separated). Then the first line would automatic be the correct length.